# react-native command line tools not working in my project directory

Tags: node.js, bash, react-native

My react-native command line tools are not working in my project directory, which is frustrating.  I used npm install -g react-native-cli.

It gives me this output:

```
/Users/myusername/.npm-packages/bin/react-native -> /Users/myusername/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js
/Users/myusername/.npm-packages/lib
└── react-native-cli@1.0.0
```

I was able to initialize a new React Native project using `react-native init <some_project>` in the `/Users/myusername` directory.

But when I move to cd `some_project`, and try to use `react-native run-ios`, I get:

```
-bash: react-native: command not found
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it with **react-native run-ios --stacktrace or --info or --debug**